# JobScheduler for start app when internet connection is lost (8.0+)

Tags: android, service, android-jobscheduler

My app use a special `foreground service` when device has no Internet connection. The app is closed if the device has Internet connection and start when the connection is lost.

I use a `BroadcastReceiver` with `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` permission on API below 8.0, app wakes up when the network changes and I begin my `foreground service` to work offline. But on 8.0 it doesn't work anymore.

How to do this on 8.0? Will I have to use `JobScheduler`? How to use it in this case?

Comment: You may have to use jobscheduler to check in regular intervals if internet is available or not and run the foreground service based on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied this solution. It works fine. But I think this is not the best solution.

```
public class MyInternetTest {

public static void scheduleJob() {
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) appContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

    JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(1, new ComponentName(appContext, MyInternetTest.NetworkSchedulerService.class))
            .setMinimumLatency(15000)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build();

    scheduler.schedule(job);
}


public static class NetworkSchedulerService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        scheduleJob();
        //
        //  Do internet check
        //
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }
}}
```

In manifest

```
 <service
        android:name=".controllers.MyInternetTest$NetworkSchedulerService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can no longer recieve the `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` broadcast in Android 8.0+. The Android website recommends the Job Scheduler but there is another solution called 
[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)  that combines the best of JobScheduler, Firebase JobDispatcher and  AlarmManager.

You can use Recurring tasks to acheive the functionality

```
new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder photoCheckBuilder =
    new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(YourWorker.class, 12,
                                    TimeUnit.HOURS);//Or any other time period
 // ...if you want, you can apply constraints to the builder here...

// Create the actual work object:
 PeriodicWorkRequest work = photoCheckBuilder.build();
// Then enqueue the recurring task:
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(work);
```

Comment: Thx for answer. Can I set 15 second period (Read that Job Scheduler does not allow to set less than 15 minutes)? I need to start the service as quickly as possible when the Internet connection is lost.

Comment: @DmitriyKholin were you ever able to find a solution for your issue? I'm having the same issue/question and would appreciate some help :).

Comment: @Abushawish pls check my answer above